Should someone say a bracha if he slept after removing his tallis?
Assuming the full time one would need to say a bracha otherwise hasn't passed but in that time the tallis wearer fell asleep. Let's say for an hour. If he had been awake he wouldn't have said a bracha but does this change by sleeping?
Edits:
There may be more than one sheeta about what the exact amount of time that needs to pass to say another bracha. Since the amount of time isn't the focus of the question I did not specify.
He took it off with the intention of putting it back on. Seemingly sleep might potentially impact this because during the time of sleep one cannot have in mind he is putting the tallis back on.

What's "the full time"?

Did he take it off? Is he putting it back on? What's happening?

This is a very confusingly organized question post. Remember "edit" is not "append". Please rewrite the whole text to flow logically and continuously for a new reader.
